# Syntax for linq query to List<string>

Tags: string, linq, casting, nvarchar

I am trying to do something like this...

```
public static List<string> GetAttachmentKeyList()
{
    DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext();

    List<string> list = from a in dc.Attachments
        select a.Att_Key.ToString().ToList();

    return list;
}
```

Visual Studio is saying...

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'.
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

What is the proper syntax???

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Give this a try

```
public static List<string> GetAttachmentKeyList()
{
    DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext();

    List<string> list = ( from a in dc.Attachments
                          select a.Att_Key.ToString() ).ToList();

    return list;
}
```

Comment: +1: Yes, in the original sample the `.ToList()` was called on the string returned by `ToString()`, so the linq expression evaluated to - _something like_ - `IEnumerable<List<char>>`, not `List<string>`

Comment: THANKS Brian & Praveen for your helpful and incredibly FAST replies!!!!  That did the trick.

Comment: This is the simplest correction to the code in the question; however [Pedro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7489012/199364) is more succint.

Answer (score 12):

try this,

```
public static List<string> GetAttachmentKeyList()
{
    DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext();

    return dc.Attachments.Select(a=>a.Att_Key).ToList();
}
```

Comment: +1 - I don't know why one would use the query syntax for such a simple problem.

Comment: If there is a better way to do this, would be interested in learning about it.

Comment: This is clearly the best answer and should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it would something like below.

```
       List<string> list = (from a in dc.Attachments
                             select a.Att_Key.ToString()).ToList<string>();
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Can we do without the Whole Paranthesis `(from...).ToList()`

Comment: @GokulE, those parentheses are needed, to know what `ToList` is being applied to - the result of that whole expression. Notice that in the original question, code was attempted, but those parentheses were missing. This applied `ToList` to a single string, inside the `select` clause. OR see Pedro's answer, for a simpler solution.