# How to convert LINQ query result to List?

Tags: linq

I need to convert linq query result to list. I tried the following code:

```cs
var qry = from a in obj.tbCourses
                     select a;

List<course> lst = new List<course>();
lst = qry.ToList();
```

The following error occurred for the above code:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 
System.Collections.Generic.List<Datalogiclayer.tbcourse> to
System.Collections.Generic.List<course>
```

Comment: how did it not help? What did you expect that didn't happen?

Comment: BTW, your code could be much shorter... `var lst = obj.tbCourses.ToList();`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax for linq query to List<string>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488980/syntax-for-linq-query-to-liststring)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No need to do so much works..

```
var query = from c in obj.tbCourses
        where ...
        select c;
```

Then you can use:

```
List<course> list_course= query.ToList<course>();
```

It works fine for me.

Comment: 2021 this can now be simplified to List<course> listCourse= query.ToList();

Answer (score 31):

```
List<course> = (from c in obj.tbCourses
                 select 
                new course(c)).toList();
```

You can convert the entity object to a list directly on the call. There are methods to converting it to different data struct (list, array, dictionary, lookup, or string)

Comment: IMHO this is the best answer. It is not only single command, but it also illustrates that `from ... select ...` linq syntax is still keeping its meaning equivalent to standard form (`tbCourses.Select()`)

Answer (score 8):

You need to somehow convert each `tbcourse` object to an instance of `course`. For instance `course` could have a constructor that takes a `tbcourse`. You could then write the query like this:

```
var qry = from c in obj.tbCourses
          select new course(c);

List<course> lst = qry.ToList();
```

Comment: This is creative!  But, it does have one drawback that your models project would now have a dependency to your data repository. While this would be fine in a smaller project, depending on your architecture and separation of concers, this could be a problem.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the `select new` LINQ keyword to explicitly convert your `tbcourse`entity into the custom type `course`. Example of `select new`:

```
var q = from o in db.Orders
        where o.Products.ProductName.StartsWith("Asset") && 
              o.PaymentApproved == true
        select new { name   = o.Contacts.FirstName + " " +
                              o.Contacts.LastName, 
                     product = o.Products.ProductName, 
                     version = o.Products.Version + 
                              (o.Products.SubVersion * 0.1)
                   };
```

http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoSQL5MinuteOverview.ashx

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is select everything into a new instance of Course, and afterwards convert them to a List.

```
var qry = from a in obj.tbCourses
                     select new Course() {
                         Course.Property = a.Property
                         ...
                     };

qry.toList<Course>();
```