# C#: Cannot convert LINQ result to a list of objects. What's wrong?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list, linq

I am trying to achieve a simple task, and I don't find a way to do it. I am trying to convert a LINQ result to a list of objects. I am following the syntax posted in [this accepted SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333619/how-to-convert-linq-query-result-to-list). Here is my code:

```
var LinqHallazgos = (from RA_Hallazgos in context.RA_Hallazgos
                            select new
                            {
                                HallazgoId = RA_Hallazgos.HallazgoId,
                                Hallazgo = RA_Hallazgos.Hallazgo
                            });

        List<RA_Hallazgos> Hallazgos = LinqHallazgos.ToList<RA_Hallazgos>();
```

And this is the error that I get:

[image]

It says that "LinqHallazgos", which is an iqueryable, doesn't contain a definition for ToList. But I see the "ToList" method in intellisense. It also says that it expect an IEnumerable but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333619/how-to-convert-linq-query-result-to-list) seems to use similar syntax.

What I am doing wrong and how in the world I get the LINQ result as a list of a particular object??

Comment: Please do not use a "Visual Studio" tag if you are asking a question, that not related to IDE

Comment: And please post error messages as text, others can't google this from images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `.ToList()`. You have an anonymous type there (the `new {}`) so you can't specify the type explicitly even if you wanted to.

Otherwise, if `RA_Hallazgos` is an actual type, use `new RA_Hallazgos{}` to avoid creating an anonymous type.

Answer (score 2):

You are making this too complex. It seems all you want to do is materialize the `DbSet<RA_Hallazgos>` to memory (*retrieve the content from the database*). If that is the case just use the `ToList()` linq extension on the `DbSet` and you are done. Note that it will retrieve everything as you did not specify a filter (*ie. any limiting predicates like Where / Take / Skip / etc*).

```
List<RA_Hallazgos> Hallazgos = context.RA_Hallazgos.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select new RA_Hallazgos
{
    HallazgoId = RA_Hallazgos.HallazgoId,
    Hallazgo = RA_Hallazgos.Hallazgo
}
List<RA_Hallazgos> Hallazgos = LinqHallazgos.ToList()();
```