# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting this error while using this `IEquality` comparer for intersection. 
Can somebody identify where I am doing it wrong?

Pleas ask if you need more information.

Comment: Help us help you - please share your code and the exact error message.

Comment: Why are you using so many `join`s? If you're using Entity Framework (aka Linq-to-Entities) then you should have Navigation Properties and `IQueryable<T>.Include( e => e.Property )` to avoid all of those.

Comment: Also, I recommend rewriting your query entirely using Extension Methods and avoiding the `from o in join x in y` syntax to be more consistent and to make code-formatting much easier to read.

Comment: @Mureinik Added error message and some more code

Comment: remove the `.ToList()` from `ComparableArticle {ArticleId = a.ArticleId}).ToList()` in all places. You need to convert to ToList() after the query is executed. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333619/how-to-convert-linq-query-result-to-list)

Comment: Then  how will i compare the count,i will get the error here oa.Intersect(da, new ArticleComparer()).Count().Equals(oa.Count)

Answer (score 3):

When you write LINQ to Entities, you must remember that eventually **all** of your LINQ expression is translated to SQL. So for every method call you make in that expression, you should think if there's a reasonable way to translate it to SQL.

Having that in mind, you can see that:

1. SQL has no notion of `.ToList()`, which is probably the source of your current error. calls to `.ToList()` should be made at the end of the expression, as a way to "materialize" the query (i.e. make EF make the actual call to the database and return results).
2. Your database knows nothing about C# interfaces. You can't expect any implementation of `IEqualityComparer` to be translatable to SQL.
3. As @Dai has noted, you seem to be using too many joins. Make sure your model has the right navigation properties between entities, and use them.